# Why does JerseyTest throw ConstraintViolationException instead of returning 400 Bad Request?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly, jersey-test-framework

I am using Jersey version 2.23.2 and I am unable to figure out how to use `JerseyTest` to test the responses for when validation fails.  For some reason, the below test throws a `ConstraintViolationException` which is wrapped in a `ProcessingException` instead of returning `400` Bad Request.  I could modify the test to check that the `ProcessingException` is thrown, but I really want to test the response.  When I run `HelloResource` in Grizzly without `JerseyTest`, I get the appropriate `400` Bad Request response. Any ideas on how to fix the `badRequestResponse()` test below?

```
package example;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class BadRequestTest extends JerseyTest {
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Hello {
        @NotNull(message = "Name is a required field.")
        private final String name;

        private Hello() {
            this(null);
        }

        public Hello(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    @Path("hello")
    public static class HelloResource {
        @POST
        public String sayHelloToMe(@Valid Hello hello) {
            return "Hello " + hello.getName() + "!";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class).property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    }

    /** Test OK Response. This Works!*/
    @Test
    public void okResponse() {
        Response response = target("hello")
                .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .post(Entity.json(new Hello("Tiny Tim")));

        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("Hello Tiny Tim!", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }

    /** Test Bad Request Response.  This Fails! */
    @Test
    public void badRequestResponse() {
        Response response = target("hello")
                .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .post(Entity.json(new Hello(null)));

        assertEquals(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Here's the exception I am getting:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: 
Exception Description: Constraints violated on marshalled bean:
example.BadRequestTest$Hello@456abb66
-->Violated constraint on property name: "Name is a required field.".
Internal Exception: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
    at example.BadRequestTest.badRequestResponse(BadRequestTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7510] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.BeanValidationException
Exception Description: Constraints violated on marshalled bean:
example.BadRequestTest$Hello@456abb66
-->Violated constraint on property name: "Name is a required field.".
Internal Exception: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.BeanValidationException.constraintViolation(BeanValidationException.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.buildConstraintViolationException(JAXBBeanValidator.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.validate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.validateAndTransformIfNeeded(JAXBMarshaller.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:949)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.buildConstraintViolationException(JAXBBeanValidator.java:383)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The test fails, yeah, but only because you forgot the `@Valid` annotation on the method parameter. So you get a 200 when you expect a 400. Other than that the test is working. I am using Jersey 2.23. What version are you using?

Comment: I updated the post to include more details.  I am using Jersey 2.23.2.  You are correct that I forgot the `@Valid` annotation (Good catch!).  However, I added it to my test and still have the same problem.  I added a copy of the exception to the post as well.

Comment: Looks like a client side error, not server. The request is not even going through. It will work if you don't use the bean. Just use the string. `Entity.json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Hello(null)));`

Comment: Maybe the messagebodywriter has something to do with the validation. I could not reproduce that error though. Maybe my project configuration was a little different

Comment: You are correct.  It is a client side error.  Are you using Jackson?  I am using MOXy and I could be wrong, but I don't believe MOXy has `ObjectMapper`.  I used the following and it worked: `Entity.json("{}");`

Comment: That's probably the reason. I was using Jackson. They might behave differently with the bean validation

Comment: `jersey-media-json-jackson` if you want to use jackson. You need to get rid of MOXy also

Comment: Looks like MOXy has validation on by default.  So, it is correctly throwing the exception on the client since the JSON I am trying to create does not validate.  By adding this method to the test, I am able to turn off validation:
    `@Override
    protected void configureClient(final ClientConfig config) {
        super.configureClient(config);
        config.register(new MoxyJsonConfig()
                .property(MarshallerProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_MODE, BeanValidationMode.NONE)
                .resolver());
    }`

Comment: @peeskillet, I'd like to give you credit for this answer as I am much obliged for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a client side problem. As you've discovered MOXy has bean validation on by default. So you are getting bean validation on the client. So the request is not even going through as the error is happening on the client. You could test this by just sending a string

```
Entity.json("{}")
```

That should get rid of the error. But if you want to use the bean, as you mentioned in the comment, you should disable the bean validation on the client with MOXy

```
@Override 
protected void configureClient(final ClientConfig config) {  
    super.configureClient(config);
    config.register(new MoxyJsonConfig() 
            .property(MarshallerProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_MODE,
                      BeanValidationMode.NONE).resolver());
}
```